# React Navigation com Typescript | Erro ao acessar a rota

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

Estou tentando criar uma navegação de rotas do tipo Stack pro meu app em React Native em Typescript, pra isso estou usando a biblioteca React Navigation. No meio dessa navegação está uma autenticação também, pois há telas que somente o usuário logado conseguirá acessar, pra fazer a autenticação uso o Firebase. Fiz toda a funcionalidade de autenticação porém na hora de navegar entre as telas públicas pras privadas estou tendo este erro:
**The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Menu"} was not handled by any navigator.
Do you have a screen named 'Menu'?**

As minhas rotas estão assim:

```
export type StackScreens = {
  Login: undefined;
  Register: undefined;
  Menu: undefined;
  Profile: undefined;
};

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<StackScreens>();

const user = auth.currentUser;

export function StackRoutes() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      initialRouteName="Login"
    >
      {!user ? (
        //PublicStack
        <Stack.Group>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} key="Login" />
          <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} key="Register" />
        </Stack.Group>
      ) : (
        //PrivateStack
        <Stack.Group>
          <Stack.Screen name="Menu" component={Menu} key="Menu" />
          <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} key="Profile" />
        </Stack.Group>
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Na tela de Login que irá navegar pro Menu, uso da seguinte forma:

```
type Props = NativeStackScreenProps<StackScreens, "Login">;


export default function Login({ navigation }: Props) {
  const handleSubmit = async (values: FormValues) => {
    ...

    const response = await loginFirebase(formatEmailOrPhone, formatPassword);

    if (response === "OK") {
      console.log("Navegando pra tela principal");
      navigation.navigate("Menu");
    } else {
      Toast.show({
        type: "error",
        text1: "Erro",
        text2: response,
      });
    }
  };

  ...
}
```

Tentei utilizar dois Navigators diferentes, um pras rotas Públicas e outro pras Privadas, porém obtive o mesmo erro, alguém pode me dizer como fazer essa navegação? Dei uma olhada na documentação e encontrei somente essa recomendação de criar o Stack.Group, porém não explicava como fazia essa navegação entre grupos diferentes.

**Versão: @react-navigation/native: 6.1.3; @react-navigation/native-stack: 6.9.9**